wildfly: Threads are getting blocked due to logging thread
We are using wildfly-9.01 for java web application.
For logging, we are using log4j-1.2.17.jar for
During load conditions application was using more CPU and became unresponsive.
After inspecting threaddump we came to know there were many threads in BLOCKED state.
Below logging thread was blocking other threads(around 100 threads)
 "EJB default - 863" #2445 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007feee00ec800 nid=0xc10c5 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fed29cc8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:56)
    - locked <0x00007ff027670520> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:69)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:82)
    at com.mypp.dms.locking.dao.LockDAO.getObjectActivityLockByLockedObjectIds(LockDAO.java:259)
    at com.mypp.collab.locking.bizlogic.AdoddleLockEJB.getObjectActivityLockByLockedObjectIds(AdoddleLockEJB.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContext.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.proceed(WeldInvocationContext.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInCallerTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:104)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor334.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContext.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.proceed(WeldInvocationContext.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:331)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00007ff03c0f32c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

stacktrace of other threads which blocked due to above thread
"EJB default - 1974" #3695 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fef8408d000 nid=0xc2451 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fece2758000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:56)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007ff027670520> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:69)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:82)
    at com.mypp.dms.forms.create.persistence.dao.FormCreateDAO.insertFormMessage(FormCreateDAO.java:246)



"EJB default - 1926" #3644 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fedc01d5000 nid=0xc241b waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fece5486000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:56)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007ff027670520> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:69)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:82)
    at com.mypp.dms.distribute.bizlogic.DistributionFacadeEJB.getDistributionGroupsForProjects(DistributionFacadeEJB.java:2855)


"EJB default - 1874" #3579 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ffa34ba1800 nid=0xc23d3 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fece8dbf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:56)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007ff027670520> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:69)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:82)
    at com.mypp.dms.forms.create.bizlogic.CreateMsgSessionEJB.getFormTypeFixedFields(CreateMsgSessionEJB.java:378)

I have referred to some of the posts that suggest upgrading log4. Other than this, are there any config/changes that need to be checked to avoid this issue?
Thanks for looking here :-)

did you try to adjust Logger buffer size ?

also try to configure asynchronous logging to decouple logging operations from the main application thread. do you need pointers on how to do that ?

Hi, @AhmadAl-Sanie I am using asynchronous logging using  with .


For logging, we are using log4j-1.2.17.jar.

You certainly compiled your application code against Log4j 1, but the library is not used at runtime. The WildFly logging subsystem has a add-logging-api-dependencies configuration option that overrides the logging APIs contained in your application with global libraries.
In your particular case log4j:log4j is replaced with the JBoss Log4j Emulation, which forwards all logging events to JBoss Log Manager.
The thread dumps you posted do not show any indications of a deadlock. JBoss Log Manager is simply not able to deliver all logs in a timely fashion. Therefore you can:

either log less as suggested in Thomas answer,
or switch to a more performant logging implementation, such as Log4j Core 2.x (see Tuning Log4j Core for performance). To bind Log4j Core 2 to Log4j 1, see Log4j 1 API migration: using Log4j 1 to Log4j 2 bridge.

Remark: The fact that your application uses Log4j 1 to log events should not have an influence on your problem. Nevertheless you should consider rewriting it in terms of a maintained logging API: Apache Commons Logging, Log4j 2 API or SLF4J for example.
All these choices will enable you to swiftly change the logging implementation of your application without rewriting your code again.
To migrate to Log4j 2 API, see Migrating from Log4j 1 API to Log4j 2 API.

Minor note on this. WildFly 9 does not support log4j2 out of the box. Really, WildFly 9 is very old at this point.

@Piotr P. Karwasz we are using Wildfly 15 [ keycloak] - can you add in your post how to plugin log4j to keycloak or to use log4j in it
We are using Custom SPI jar [ not war or ear] how do we plugin in wildfly the same

@Karthik_Rajendiran: if you are having problems with Keycloak, please create new question. The OP doesn't mention Keycloak at all.

You write that During load conditions application [...] became unresponsives.
Your stack traces all show that you do debug level logging:
...
at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:82)
...

IMHO during load conditions logging should be configured to accept only levels info and above, maybe even only levels warning and above - except if you are currently trying to fix some problems.
This does not mean that you need to remove those log.debug() statements. You can raise the level of the loggers (log4j.rootLogger = WARN, someappender).
